# how to make columns sortable with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

here is my view where I am trying to sort

```
 <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("WardName", "CompletedReq", new { strSortBy = "WardName" })

       @*@ @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WARD_NAME)*@
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("WardLocation", "CompletedReq", new { strSortBy = "WardLocation" })
       @*@ @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WARD_LOCATION)*@
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("ItemID", "CompletedReq", new { strSortBy = "ItemID" })
        @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEM_ID)*@
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("ItemType", "CompletedReq", new { strSortBy = "ItemType" })
        @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEM_TYPE)*@
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("ItemName", "CompletedReq", new { strSortBy = "ItemName" })
        @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEM_NAME)*@

        </th>
    </tr>
```

I wrote my query with linq but I want to do a sort on the orderby I do this successful with entity framework on one table but not sure how I do this on these tables on my joins

```
     var query =
                       from wr in db.Ward_Req
                       join w in db.Wards
                       on wr.WARD_ID equals w.WARD_ID
                       join rl in db.Req_Line
                       on wr.REQ_ID equals rl.REQ_ID
                       join m in db.Materials
                       on rl.ITEM_ID equals m.ITEM_ID
                       where wr.STATUS == "C"
                       orderby w.WARD_NAME descending
                       select new Reports
                       {
                           WARD_NAME = w.WARD_NAME,
                           WARD_LOCATION = w.WARD_LOCATION,
                           ITEM_ID = m.ITEM_ID,
                           ITEM_TYPE = m.ITEM_TYPE,
                           ITEM_NAME = m.ITEM_NAME

                       };
            return View(query.ToList());
```

so in my order by I want to pass in the strSortby in like a switch statement like i did on this part but I may not be doing it right. Here is the switch I wrote on my other controller that did the sort successfully.

```
     public ActionResult Index(string strSortBy)
    {            
        var staffs = db.Staffs.Include(s => s.Staff2);
        switch (strSortBy)
        {
            case "fname":
                staffs = staffs.OrderBy(s => s.FNAME);
                break;
            case "lname":
                staffs = staffs.OrderBy(s => s.LNAME);
                break;
            case "phone":
                staffs = staffs.OrderBy(s => s.TELEPHONE);
                break;
            case "gender":
                staffs = staffs.OrderBy(s => s.GENDER);
                break;
            case "position":
                staffs = staffs.OrderBy(s => s.POSITION);
                break;
            case "status":
                staffs = staffs.OrderBy(s => s.STATUS);
                break;
            case "username":
                staffs = staffs.OrderBy(s => s.USERNAME);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return View(staffs.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: It should be no different from what your doing in the other view. - `switch (strSortBy) { case "WardLocation": query = query.OrderBy(s => s.WARD_LOCATION); break; case "ItemID": query.OrderBy(s => s.ITEM_ID);break; etc }`

Comment: would I put that after my query?

Comment: do I take out the orderby in my linq query?

Comment: Yes (and before the `return View(query.ToList())` - but do you really need `ToList()`?). And you can remove the `orderby w.WARD_NAME descending` (no point ordering it then reordering it again based on another criteria)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the code I did thank you Stephen Muecke it works perfect I was just over thinking it you are greatly appreciated though

```
            var query =
                       from wr in db.Ward_Req
                       join w in db.Wards
                       on wr.WARD_ID equals w.WARD_ID
                       join rl in db.Req_Line
                       on wr.REQ_ID equals rl.REQ_ID
                       join m in db.Materials
                       on rl.ITEM_ID equals m.ITEM_ID
                       where wr.STATUS == "C"
                       orderby w.WARD_NAME descending
                       select new Reports
                       {
                           WARD_NAME = w.WARD_NAME,
                           WARD_LOCATION = w.WARD_LOCATION,
                           ITEM_ID = m.ITEM_ID,
                           ITEM_TYPE = m.ITEM_TYPE,
                           ITEM_NAME = m.ITEM_NAME

                       };

            switch (strSortBy)
            {
                case "WardName":
                    query = query.OrderBy(s => s.WARD_NAME);
                    break;
                case "WardLocation":
                    query = query.OrderBy(s => s.WARD_LOCATION);
                    break;
                case "ItemID":
                    query = query.OrderBy(s => s.ITEM_ID);
                    break;
                case "ItemType":
                    query = query.OrderBy(s => s.ITEM_TYPE);
                    break;
                case "ItemName":
                    query = query.OrderBy(s => s.ITEM_NAME);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return View(query.ToList());
```